# Change button labels in CKEditor 5 toolbar

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a custom toolbar for CKEditor 5 with options like this:
 `customToolbar: ['insertTable', 'fileUpload', 'mediaEmbed']`

Is there a way to customize the title for these features?

I saw a way to customize heading like this:

```
heading: {
        options: [
            { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Body copy', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
            { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Sub Header', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
    }
```

But not sure how to do it with other features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Buttons](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_buttonview-ButtonView.html) in CKEditor5 UI have the (observable) [`#label`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_ui_button_buttonview-ButtonView.html#member-label) property. Changing it will be immediately reflected in DOM.

```
yourToolbar.items.get( 2 ).label = "Foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as it took me a sec to figure out how to get a hold of the toolbar object from @oleq post.

```
ClassicEditor
  .create( document.querySelector('#editor'))
  .then(editor => {
     editor.ui.view.toolbar.items.get(0).label = 'YEAH BUDDY'
  });
```